# Make an hourly dataset full

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

I have a dataset with a date-time vector (format is m/d/y h:m) that looks like this:

```
june2018_2$datetime
  [1] "6/1/2018 1:00"   "6/1/2018 2:00"   "6/1/2018 3:00"   "6/1/2018 4:00"
```

And I have 61 other variables that are all numeric (with some already missing values indicated with 'NA'). My date time vector is missing some hourly slots and I want to make the date-time vector full and fill in missing spots in the other 61 variables with 'NA'. I tried to use what's already out there but I can't seem to find some code or function that works for what I'm specifically working with. Any tips?

Comment: The datetime vector starts at 6/1/2018 1:00 and ends at 7/1/2018 0:00

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example please. You might use replace_with_na function.

Answer (score 0):

If your `datetime` is not in POSIXct then could be mutated. With `complete` you can fill in rows by the hour. Other columns in the data frame will be `NA`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(datetime = as.POSIXct(datetime, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")) %>%
  complete(datetime = seq(from = first(datetime), to = last(datetime), by = "hours"))
```

For example, if you have test data:

```
set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(
  datetime = c("6/1/2018 1:00",   "6/1/2018 3:00",   "6/1/2018 5:00",   "6/1/2018 9:00"),
  var1 = sample(10,4)
)
```

The output would be:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 2
  datetime             var1
  <dttm>              <int>
1 2018-06-01 01:00:00     3
2 2018-06-01 02:00:00    NA
3 2018-06-01 03:00:00    10
4 2018-06-01 04:00:00    NA
5 2018-06-01 05:00:00     2
6 2018-06-01 06:00:00    NA
7 2018-06-01 07:00:00    NA
8 2018-06-01 08:00:00    NA
9 2018-06-01 09:00:00     8
```

Comment: I made the datetime vector by creating a new column like this: june2018 <- june2018 %>%
  mutate(datetime = as_datetime(paste(june2018$date, june2018$newHour))). Does that mean it's in POSIXct? or no?

Comment: I believe `as_datetime` from `lubridate` returns `POSIXlt` not `POSIXct`.